# Adding schema itemprop image to the_post_thumbnail with filters

Tags: post-thumbnails, filters

I have tried to apply filters to the_post_thumbnail() function using

```
apply_filters( 'post_thumbnail_html', $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr );
```

Here's the code I have come up with but doesn't seem to work completely

```
    function red_adjust_image_schema($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt) 
{
    $html = '<div class="image-container" itemprop="image">'. $html . '</div>';

    return $html;
}
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'red_adjust_image_schema', 20, 8);
```

How can I add itemprop="image" to the actual image element so it registers properly? Right now it seem like I can only do a container and wrap around $html?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've simply the wrong arguments (incl. the list of them).

```
$caption, $title, $align, $url, $alt
```

are too much in there.

And `$attr` is missing. Not that it matters how you name the vars (as long as they start with a character), but it's easier to read for later readers.

```
function wpse76536_image_schema( $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr ) 
{
    return "<div class='image-container' itemprop='image'>{$html}</div>";
}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wpse76536_image_schema', 10, 5 );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just add a new attribute:

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'ipwp_img_attr', 10, 2);
    function ipwp_img_attr($attr) {
    $attr['itemprop'] = 'image';
    return $attr;
}
```

This way there will just be a new attribute, without the need to search and replace any code  - See my previous version:

```
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html','mediaboxlv_image_itemprop',10,3 );
function mediaboxlv_image_itemprop($html, $post_id, $post_image_id){
    $html = str_replace('src',' itemprop="image" src',$html);
    return $html;
}
```