# hrecipe microformat tag to "featured image"

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have a website made with wordpress which includes recipes. Now I would like to add the "photo" `hrecipe` Microformat tag in order to have a thumbnail on Google searches ([hrecipe photo tag](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173379))

My recipes pictures come from the featured image section. How can I now add `itemprop="photo"` to the `<img>` tag?

For example:

```
  <img itemprop="photo" src="apple-pie.jpg" />
```

This is were my Thumbnail is created:

```
<div class="post-thumb">

    <?php if( !is_singular() ) { ?>
        <a title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s', 'zilla'), get_the_title()); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('blog-large'); ?></a>

    <?php } else {
        the_post_thumbnail('blog-large');

    } ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the filter `post_thumbnail_html`. The callback takes 5 parameters, the first (`$html`) is the one that's returned and that we modify, and the others can be helpful to build the modification.

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'add_tag_to_featured_wpse_95469', 10, 5 );

function add_tag_to_featured_wpse_95469( $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr )
{
    $modify = str_replace( '<img', '<img itemprop="photo"', $html );
    return $modify;
}
```

<sub>Relevant Q&A: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

from [Adding schema itemprop image to the_post_thumbnail with filters](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/87340/7577) :

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'ipwp_img_attr', 10, 2);
function ipwp_img_attr($attr) {
  $attr['itemprop'] = 'photo';
  // OR better 
  // $attr['itemprop'] = 'image';
  return $attr;
}
```