# Add Schema Image Designation Inside a Wordpress Function?

Tags: html

I would like to add itemprop="articleSection" to a thumbnail.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thmb-index'); ?>
```

This is what I've tried:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail',array('itemprop'=>'image')); ?>
```

How can I do this in the most simple and effective way?  Preferably, I would like to incorporate it into `<?php the_post_thumbnail('thmb-index'); ?>` itself, not functions.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do works for me. That is, this works when I try it:

```
the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail',array('itemprop'=> 'articleSection'));
```

I get the `itemprop` attribute is my `<img` tag. If that isn't working for you I can only guess at why. Possibly there is a filter causing problems.

For a more global solution, the following will add that `itemprop` to anything that uses the `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` filter, which `the_post_thumbnail` does.

```
function alter_att_attributes_wpse_102551($attr) {
  $attr['itemprop'] = 'articleSection';
  return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'alter_att_attributes_wpse_102551');
```

You may need conditions to prevent that from running as globally as it will left as it is.

Comment: I'm more looking for something that adds it to specific occurrences, this was helpful though.

Comment: I thought you probably would need something more specific. Post your precise requirements and I will edit the answer.

Comment: Just adding it to that specific thumbnail - probably something that's just directly incorporated rather than functions.php based.

Answer (score 0):

there is very similar answer about itemprop properties and attributes to thumbnails - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/87340/7577 (Adding schema itemprop image to the_post_thumbnail with filters)